# How to to edit svg and send it as data

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I have inline SVG in html and i edit paths color with javascript. I want to be able to save that SVG and send it to server as data and later display it to other devices. What is best way to do it. If there is any libary to do so or something. I  am using angular.

Comment: Can you please include a code sample to better understand the issue?

Comment: https://www.caossuits.com/#/camerajacket see how you can color the svg path, i want to rebuild this website because it is using angularjs and i want to make more efficient way than it has now... currently it has some directives and json files that represent svg with ids...

Comment: https://github.com/LaMbA3/caos 
see github if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **component.html**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" #container>
    <!-- your svg here -->
</svg>
```

In **component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('container')
container: ElementRef;

saveSvg() {
  const svg = this.container.nativeElement.outerHTML;
  // your code to save svg
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference, say `el`, to the root `<svg />` element (e.g. from `document.getElementById()`), you can retrieve the current contents of the SVG via `el.outerHTML`.

This value is a string that you can then send to your backend in whatever way you wish.